# Better way to add types to props in a functional component in NextJS Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to add types when there are multiple props. For ex:

```
export default function Posts({ source, frontMatter }) {
...
}
```

One way I found is to first create wrapper type and then create parameter type. For ex:

```
type Props = {
  source: string;
  frontMatter: FrontMatter;
};

type FrontMatter = {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  date: string;
};


export default function Posts({ source, frontMatter }:Props) {
...
}
```

But is there a way to avoid that extra `Props` type because I'm using that for only this function. I'm hoping to achieve something like this:

```
export default function Posts({ source:string, frontMatter:FrontMatter }) {...}
```

Answer (score 6):

i think its ur personal decision ,ur first solution is true and if it works fine u can use it, i prefer using somthing like this :

```
interface PostProps {
  source: string;
  frontMatter: {
    title: string;
    author: string;
    date: string;
  }
}

export const Posts: React.FC<PostProps> = ({source,frontMatter}) => {
...
}
```

also ur suggested way can be like this :

```
export default function Posts({source,frontMatter}:{source: string,frontMatter:FrontMatter}) {
...
}
```

Comment: `PostProps` is fine for single method in a file but makes an issue for multiple methods.. `PostProps2`, `PostProps2` etc are not looking fine. And, thanks for the correct syntax `{source,frontMatter}:{source: string,frontMatter:FrontMatter}`

Comment: u can name first part of it with ur function name like `export default function Books` with `interface BooksProps`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the interface like below:-

```
interface PostConfig {
  source: string;
  frontMatter: FrontMatterConfig;
}

interface FrontMatterConfig {
  title: string;
  author: string;
  date: string;
}
```

And also mention the typing for the component:-

```
const Posts: FunctionComponent<PostConfig> = ({
  source,
  frontMatter: { title, author, date }
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <b>{source}</b>
      <div>{title}</div>
      <div>{author}</div>
      <div>{date}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Sample Code:- https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-dijkstra-t4sfc?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: As I mentioned, I want to avoid `PostConfig` interface/type